# Optimalize loading page

Tags: c#, wpf, loading

So I'm dealing with problem in `WPF`.

I have page which load when you click button with `RichTextBox` as output data box.

Problem is, it checks if file is accesible on the `FTP`, but it first do checks so it takes a while and then it displays page with output.

I wana first display page with output box and then it will start showing data (like you see in installers etc).

This is code in page itself:

```
public partial class ArtaActionsPage : Page
{
    public ArtaActionsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        AddBlackLine("");
        AddBlackLine("Checking if everything is ready...");
        AddBlackLine("");

        bool AdobeReady = false;
        bool SevenZipReady = false;
        bool JavaReady = false;
        bool EsetReady = false;

        if (Global_Action_Variables.Arta_Variables.ArtaAdobeSwitch == true)
        {
            AddBlackLine("Checking for Adobe installator...");
            bool CheckForAdobe = General_Functions.CheckIfFileExistsOnFTP("Ultra_Script/Basic_SW/Adobe_Reader.exe");
            if(CheckForAdobe == true)
            {
                AddGreenLine("Installer for Adobe accesible.");
                AdobeReady = true;
            }
            else
            {
                AddRedLine("Installer not accesible on FTP!!! Canceling job...");
                AddRedLine("Check FTP repozitary if file in Ultra_Script/Basic_SW/Adobe_Reader.exe exists and ftp account have enough rights for this file.");
            }
        }

        if (Global_Action_Variables.Arta_Variables.ArtaSevenZip == true)
        {
            AddBlackLine("");
            AddBlackLine("");
            AddBlackLine("Checking for SevenZip installer...");
            bool CheckForSevenZip = General_Functions.CheckIfFileExistsOnFTP("Ultra_Script/Basic_SW/7zip.exe");
            if(CheckForSevenZip == true)
            {
                AddGreenLine("Installer for 7zip accesible.");
                SevenZipReady = true;
            }
            else
            {
                AddRedLine("Installer not accesible on FTP!!! Canceling job...");
                AddRedLine("Check FTP repozitary if file in Ultra_Script/Basic_SW/7zip.exe exists and ftp account have enough rights for this file.");
            }
        }

        if(Global_Action_Variables.Arta_Variables.ArtaJava == true)
        {
            AddBlackLine("");
            AddBlackLine("");
            AddBlackLine("Checking for Java installer...");
            bool CheckForJava = General_Functions.CheckIfFileExistsOnFTP("Ultra_Script/Basic_SW/JaVa.exe");
            if(CheckForJava == true)
            {
                AddGreenLine("Installer for Java accesible");
                JavaReady = true;
            }
            else
            {
                AddRedLine("Installer not accesible on FTP!!! Canceling job...");
                AddRedLine("Check FTP repozitary if file in Ultra_Script/Basic_SW/JaVa.exe exists and ftp account have enough rights for this file.");
            }
        }

        if(Global_Action_Variables.Arta_Variables.ArtaEset == true)
        {
            AddBlackLine("");
            AddBlackLine("");
            AddBlackLine("Checking for Arta ESET installer...");
            bool CheckForArtaEset = General_Functions.CheckIfFileExistsOnFTP("Ultra_Script/Basic_SW/Arta/ERA_ESET.exe");
            if(CheckForArtaEset == true)
            {
                AddGreenLine("Installer for ESET accesible");
                EsetReady = true;
            }
            else
            {
                AddRedLine("Installer not accesible on FTP!!! Canceling job...");
                AddRedLine("Check FTP repozitary if file in UUltra_Script/Basic_SW/Arta/ERA_ESET.exe exists and ftp account have enough rights for this file.");
            }
        }

        if(AdobeReady == true)
        {
            AddBlackLine("");
            AddBlackLine("");
            AddBlackLine("Test");
            General_Functions.DownloadFileFromFTP("Ultra_Script/Basic_SW/Adobe_Reader.exe", "Adobe_Reader.exe");
        }
        else
        {
            AddBlackLine("");
            AddRedLine("Failed.");
        }
    }

    private void AddRedLine(string text)
    {
        TextRange tr = new TextRange(outputBox.Document.ContentEnd, outputBox.Document.ContentEnd);
        tr.Text = text;
        tr.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Red);
        outputBox.AppendText("\r");
        outputBox.ScrollToEnd();
    }

    private void AddGreenLine(string text)
    {
        TextRange tr = new TextRange(outputBox.Document.ContentEnd, outputBox.Document.ContentEnd);
        tr.Text = text;
        tr.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Green);
        outputBox.ScrollToEnd();
    }

    private void AddBlackLine(string text)
    {
        TextRange tr = new TextRange(outputBox.Document.ContentEnd, outputBox.Document.ContentEnd);
        tr.Text = text;
        tr.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Black);
        outputBox.AppendText("\r");
        outputBox.ScrollToEnd();
    }
}
```

And this is code of button who shows the new page:

```
private void ArtaDoITButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (File.Exists("settings.xml"))
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Information));
        FileStream read = new FileStream("settings.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
        Information info = (Information)xs.Deserialize(read);

        try
        {
            string a = info.FtpPassword;
            string FTPPassword = EncryDecryptor.Decrypt(a);
            bool TestFTP = General_Functions.isValidConnection(info.HDSynologyIP, info.FtpUsername, FTPPassword);
            if(TestFTP == true)
            {
                ArtaActionsFrame.Content = new ArtaActionsPage();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failed login to FTP repozitary. Check your credentials in settings.");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            read.Close();
        }
        read.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Chybí settings file!!");
    }
}
```

Initializaon of page:

```
public ArtaActionsPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += OnLoaded;
}
```

Anybody have idea how to optimize that so it wont do checks before it loads the page?

Thanks for all answers.

Comment: You should go with MVVM pattern and events.

Comment: There is too much code here for this question that is totally irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the `Page` asynchronously using `async`/`await`. All the initialization procedure should be moved into the `ArtaActionsPage` into a public `InitalizeAsync()` method:

The load page event handler:

```
private async void ArtaDoITButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  if (!File.Exists("settings.xml"))
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Chybí settings file!!");
    return;
  }

  var nextPage = new ArtaActionsPage();

  // Show the page immediately
  ArtaActionsFrame.Content = nextPage;

  if (!await nextPage.TryInitializeAsync())
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Failed login to FTP repozitary. Check your credentials in settings.");

    // Show previous page again
  }
}
```

Page.xaml.cs:

```
private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
{}

public async Task<bool> TryInitializeAsync()
{
  bool ftpIsValid = await ValidateFtpAsync();
  if (!ftpIsValid)
  {        
    return false;
  }

  await CheckIfFileExistsOnFTPAsync();
  return true;
}

private async Task<bool> ValidateFtpAsync()
{
  return await Task.Run(
    () =>
    {
      var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Information));
      using (var read = new FileStream("settings.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
      {
        Information info = (Information) xs.Deserialize(read);

        try
        {
          string a = info.FtpPassword;
          string fTPPassword = EncryDecryptor.Decrypt(a);
          return General_Functions.isValidConnection(info.HDSynologyIP, info.FtpUsername, FTPPassword);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
      }

      return false;
    });
}

public async Task CheckIfFileExistsOnFTPAsync()
{
  bool ftpIsValid = await ValidateFtpAsync();
  if (!ftpIsValid)
  {        
    return false;
  }

  await Task.Run(
    () =>
    {
      AddBlackLine("");
      AddBlackLine("Checking if everything is ready...");
      AddBlackLine("");

      bool AdobeReady = false;
      bool SevenZipReady = false;
      bool JavaReady = false;
      bool EsetReady = false;

      if (Global_Action_Variables.Arta_Variables.ArtaAdobeSwitch == true)
      {
        AddBlackLine("Checking for Adobe installator...");
        bool CheckForAdobe = General_Functions.CheckIfFileExistsOnFTP("Ultra_Script/Basic_SW/Adobe_Reader.exe");
        if (CheckForAdobe == true)
        {
          AddGreenLine("Installer for Adobe accesible.");
          AdobeReady = true;
        }
        else
        {
          AddRedLine("Installer not accesible on FTP!!! Canceling job...");
          AddRedLine(
            "Check FTP repozitary if file in Ultra_Script/Basic_SW/Adobe_Reader.exe exists and ftp account have enough rights for this file.");
        }
      }

      if (Global_Action_Variables.Arta_Variables.ArtaSevenZip == true)
      {
        AddBlackLine("");
        AddBlackLine("");
        AddBlackLine("Checking for SevenZip installer...");
        bool CheckForSevenZip = General_Functions.CheckIfFileExistsOnFTP("Ultra_Script/Basic_SW/7zip.exe");
        if (CheckForSevenZip == true)
        {
          AddGreenLine("Installer for 7zip accesible.");
          SevenZipReady = true;
        }
        else
        {
          AddRedLine("Installer not accesible on FTP!!! Canceling job...");
          AddRedLine(
            "Check FTP repozitary if file in Ultra_Script/Basic_SW/7zip.exe exists and ftp account have enough rights for this file.");
        }
      }

      if (Global_Action_Variables.Arta_Variables.ArtaJava == true)
      {
        AddBlackLine("");
        AddBlackLine("");
        AddBlackLine("Checking for Java installer...");
        bool CheckForJava = General_Functions.CheckIfFileExistsOnFTP("Ultra_Script/Basic_SW/JaVa.exe");
        if (CheckForJava == true)
        {
          AddGreenLine("Installer for Java accesible");
          JavaReady = true;
        }
        else
        {
          AddRedLine("Installer not accesible on FTP!!! Canceling job...");
          AddRedLine(
            "Check FTP repozitary if file in Ultra_Script/Basic_SW/JaVa.exe exists and ftp account have enough rights for this file.");
        }
      }

      if (Global_Action_Variables.Arta_Variables.ArtaEset == true)
      {
        AddBlackLine("");
        AddBlackLine("");
        AddBlackLine("Checking for Arta ESET installer...");
        bool CheckForArtaEset = General_Functions.CheckIfFileExistsOnFTP("Ultra_Script/Basic_SW/Arta/ERA_ESET.exe");
        if (CheckForArtaEset == true)
        {
          AddGreenLine("Installer for ESET accesible");
          EsetReady = true;
        }
        else
        {
          AddRedLine("Installer not accesible on FTP!!! Canceling job...");
          AddRedLine(
            "Check FTP repozitary if file in UUltra_Script/Basic_SW/Arta/ERA_ESET.exe exists and ftp account have enough rights for this file.");
        }
      }

      if (AdobeReady == true)
      {
        AddBlackLine("");
        AddBlackLine("");
        AddBlackLine("Test");
        General_Functions.DownloadFileFromFTP("Ultra_Script/Basic_SW/Adobe_Reader.exe", "Adobe_Reader.exe");
      }
      else
      {
        AddBlackLine("");
        AddRedLine("Failed.");
      }
    });
}
```

Also consider to convert `General_Functions.CheckIfFileExistsOnFTP()` to an `async` method.

Now the `ArtaActionsPage` is immediately shown. `InitializeAsync` returns a `bool` whether initialization failed or not. If it has failed you can handle this scenario e.g. by showing your message and then navigate back to the previous page.

Comment: just one little question:

at "CheckIfFIleExistsOnFTPAsync" function its a Task method and im return false shouldnt it be public async Task<bool>? or should i return Task<T>?

Cause im getting this error:
Since 'ArtaActionsPage.CheckIfFileExistsOnFTPAsync()' is an async method that returns 'Task', a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression

Comment: In my example `CheckIfFIleExistsOnFTPAsync` doesn't return a value (`void`). That's why the return type is `Task`. If you wish to return a value like a `bool`  you must change the return type to `Task<bool>`. It's always `Task` for a `void`  method or `Task<TReturn>` where `TReturn` has to be replaced with the return type of the method (generic).

Comment: and ValidateFtpAsync returns always false, but i try to figure it out by myself you helped me enough, thanks :-)

Comment: `false` is returned only when an exception is thrown or `General_Functions.isValidConnection(info.HDSynologyIP, info.FtpUsername, FTPPassword);` fails.

Comment: Oh I found an error. I updated the code of `ValidateFtpAsync`. It must be `return await Task.Run(......`. The `return` was missing and therefore the last return was executed which returns false. Sorry! Add one `return` to `await` and remove the last `return false` in `ValidateFtpAsync`.

Comment: Btw can i all these functions move to OnLoaded method? Cause i need them to be there or it wont show any text cause that page isactually "richtextbox" on the page.

Comment: Whicj functions? `ValidateAsync` and `CheckIfFileExistsOnFTPAsync`? Isn't it working right now? The `ArtaActionsPage` should load adn show the `RichTextBox`. Then inside the `ArtaActionsPage` the `RichTextBox` is updated. It should be like this... Is he behavior different?

Comment: dont worry i figured it out i made OnLoaded async method and called await CheckIfFileExistsOnFTPAsync in it and it works now like i need.

Comment: Ok so it dont work as expected. Dealing with that problem for a week and didnt found solution :D

When i added: await CheckIfFileExistsOnFTPAsync(); to OnLoaded it actually calls it twice in TryInitializaceAsync method and in OnLoaded method so it will run twice and it does problems. But when i dont have it in OnLoaded method my richtextbox is not filling with data. Can i somehow move TryInitializaceAsync method into OnLoaded method?

Comment: Have you tried the example from the answer where `OnLoaded` is empty? If you want to move something into ? `OnLoaded` then declare it `async` and ONLY move `TryInitializeAsync` to it... I wonder what you are doing. It should work.